# Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments

Tags: swift, swiftui, uipickerview

So I'm trying to create a Picker in SwiftUI that uses every item of an array. Xcode says "Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments" when I try to let it use the item of the array (as visible in the code)

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerPicker: View {
    @State var selectedTime = 0
    
    let availableMinutes = Array(1 ... 59)
    private let pickerStyle = SegmentedPickerStyle()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selectedTime, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< availableMinutes.count) {_ in
                    Text("\(self.availableMinutes[$0]) min")
                }
                
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: Remove `_ in` to use anonymous arguments. `_` means you don't need an argument or return value. Another way is to replace the underscore with a variable name like `index in` and then use it in the closure, `Text("\(self.availableMinutes[index]) min")`

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim alluded to, anonymous arguments are the `$0`, `$1`, arguments that are just based on the order of the parameters.
The full syntax for a closure body is

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

If you don't provide a list of parameters, you need to use the anonymous argument `$0` / `$1` syntax mentioned above.

If you provide parameter names, you **can't** use anonymous arguments. You have to use the names you provide.

The `_` in your closure is telling the compiler that your closure code is going to ignore the parameter completely. Once you do that, the parameter is inaccessible in the body of the closure. (Note that you can ignore some parameters and map others to names.)

Either get rid of the `_ in` part of your closure and use anonymous arguments or change `_` to a parameter name like `index` (As suggested by Joakim in their comment.)